# Keep CanvasWatchFaceService Watchface From Sleeping?

Tags: wear-os

Is this possible? I have tried inflating and adding a layout that has `android:keepScreenOn="true"` and I have tried creating a WakeLock during onCreate() like this:

```
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "WatchFaceWakelockTag");
        wakeLock.acquire();
```

These seem to have no effect. I do have the permission set in my wearable app manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Why do you wanna kill the watch battery?

Comment: While writing the watchface code, you currently have to keep reaching over to touch the watchface and wake it up. It's a bad development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (at the moment) no way of keeping the screen on. Believe me I've tried... And even asked people at Google working on Android Wear.